# I am not able to bring up my pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I installed pycharm on my linux machine, updated JDK, however while calling pycharm.sh from the terminal no output is provided, file is having executable rights,

pycharm-community-2016.2.1]$bin/pycharm.sh

Terminal remains stuck forever

Comment: Have you tried opening that shell script and inspecting what could be the issue?

Comment: I don't know much about it, however I have set a new JAVA_HOME path pointing to the latest JDK. However it doesn't make any difference with the old or the new one

Comment: I assume Intellij IDEA has the same problem? And why are you running from the command line? Shouldn't you install from your package manager, which would put an application link somewhere, and you could run that?

Comment: this is a company machine and we don't have a GUI, just a terminal. Do you have the steps to install using package manager?

Comment: Then how do you expect to run an IDE that requires a graphical interface? Or are you trying to SSH forward it?

Comment: Thats where in JDK 1.8 comes in, it allows application to run in GUI mode

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by GUI mode, but you just said that you didn't have a GUI

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a terminal on which I am running my python, however using vim editor can be sometimes overwhelming to go thru the scripts. So I have installed pycharm in one of my directory. And when we run pycharm.sh on the terminal using jdk 1.8 it will get us a GUI interface, just like you have when you double click an icon.

Comment: I'm not aware of a terminal interface for PyCharm, and I still don't understand how Java 8 would enable it to have one since that seems application specific.

Comment: I rolled back to the previous version of pycharm and now I see following error
pycharm.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
[  14191]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Project files cannot be watched (are they under network mount?)